# Evento .click() do jQuery, não funciona com tag <button> ( com Bootstrap 3 )

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um website com 2 ficheiros (index.php e modals.php).
No index.php uso `include("modals.php");` e no modals.php tenho vários modals que são gerados de forma dinâmica, de acordo com as informações na DB.

No modals.php tenho 2 botões (um criado utilizando a tag `<button>Abre</button>` e outro utilizando a tag `<input type"button" value="Abre" />`.

O meu objectivo é utilizar a tag `<button></button>` para dar trigger no evento, pois eu estou a utilizar o Bootstrap 3 e quero que o botão não tenha texto mas sim um glyphicon.

No index.php tenho:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".botaoDoModal").click(function () {
        alert("Funciona!");
    });

});
</script>
```

mas esse script só funciona quando adiciono a `class="botaoDoModal"` à tag `<input>`, o mesmo não acontece com a tag `<button></button>`.

Não sei qual a razão, ou se me enganei e nalguma parte...

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é demasiado localizada e não é possivel reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Coloca o resultado final(o código todo) para podermos analisar melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu nao sei qual era o erro, mas eu copiei outro botao que tinha algures no código e colei, adicionei a classe e funcionou, deve ter sido um erro de sintaxe

Comment: Sim, possivelmente

Answer (score 1):

Prefira sempre usar o evento [***`.on()`***](http://api.jquery.com/on/) no lugar de [***`click()`***](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Porque você pode ter elementos gerados dinamicamente (por exemplo proveniente de uma chamada de AJAX), você pode querer ter o mesmo manipulador de clique que foi previamente ligado para o mesmo seletor de elemento "delegando" o evento clique usando on() como argumento para outros elementos criados dinamicamente.

Segue um artigo muito bom do site Tableless sobre o .on() e .off():
http://tableless.com.br/jquery-conheca-os-metodos-on-e-off/